# Authenticate React Native App using AWS Cognito or AWS Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I want to authenticate a react native app using ***AWS Cognito*** rather than using ***AWS Amplify*** due to the cost factor. **Cognito** provides all the user authentication providers and it is very cost-friendly to the developer. And **Amplify** is very good, but it provides many unnecessary things which I don't require. Please provides me preferred procedures to config **AWS Cognito** in many react native app or provide me a way where I will you only the required things for my react native app like authentication, datastore, manage user and storage in **AWS Amplify**.

And Also can anybody explain to me the pricing of **AWS Amplify**, please tell me what that underline statement means
[image: AWS Amplify Pricing]

please provide me a proper way to configure AWS Cognito or AWS Amplify (Using only some specific platform), and please me to understand the pricing of AWS Amplify

Comment: might help: https://github.com/AirLabsTeam/react-native-aws-cognito-js/issues/2#issuecomment-300605889

Comment: also: https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazon-cognito-identity-js